# Repetitive C# code

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports

I'm creating a small application where I generate 12 PDF files from a crystal report with one single click. Each PDF file has different parameters.
The code is working but I would like to make it shorter because it is very repetitive. Since I'm new in programming I don't know how to achieve this.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here is the code.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cryRpt.Load(@"\\klb-lims\Crystal\TrendFailure.rpt");


        cryRpt.Load(@"\\Server\Crystal\TrendFailure.rpt");

        ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
        DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
        PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();

         try
        {

            //GENCHEM
            cryRpt.SetParameterValue("AnalysisType", "GENCHEM");
            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = (GENCHEM);
            CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;

            {
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
            }
              cryRpt.Export();


              //IC
              cryRpt.SetParameterValue("AnalysisType", "IC");
              CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = (IC);
              CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;

              {
                  CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                  CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                  CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                  CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
              }
              cryRpt.Export();

              //ICPMS
              cryRpt.SetParameterValue("AnalysisType", "ICPMS");
              CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = (ICPMS);
              CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;

              {
                  CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                  CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                  CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                  CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
              }
              cryRpt.Export();

              //ICPOES
              cryRpt.SetParameterValue("AnalysisType", "ICPOES");
              CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = (ICPOES);
              CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;

              {
                  CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                  CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                  CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                  CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
              }
              cryRpt.Export();
}
  catch (Exception ex)

         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

         }
```

I din't include the 13 blocks but you can have an idea about what I'm talking about.

Below are the strings that I use for saving the PDF files. 
The crystal report parameters are fixed.

```
    string GENCHEM = "c:\\temp\\GENCHEM_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string IC = "c:\\temp\\IC_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string ICPMS = "c:\\temp\\ICPMS_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string ICPOES = "c:\\temp\\ICPOES_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string METALS = "c:\\temp\\METALS_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string MICRO = "c:\\temp\\MICRO_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string ORGANIC = "c:\\temp\\ORGANIC_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string SOILPREP = "c:\\temp\\SOILPREP_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string SUBOUT = "c:\\temp\\SUBOUT_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string SVOC = "c:\\temp\\SVOC_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string VOC = "c:\\temp\\VOC_TrendFailure.pdf";
    string WASTEWATER = "c:\\temp\\WASTEWATER_TrendFailure.pdf";
```

Comment: move the core code to a method and pass the non repeating elements as parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with whatever library you seem to be using here, but I think a good approach would be to put those thirteen strings into an array of [tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then, you would do:

```
List<Tuple<String, String>> entries = new List<Tuple<String, String>>();
entries.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("GENCHEM, "c:\\temp\\GENCHEM_TrendFailure.pdf");
entries.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("IC, ""c:\\temp\\IC_TrendFailure.pdf"");
```

and so on.

Then you would loop through the list and say:

```
for (Tuple<String, String> entry : entries)
{
    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("AnalysisType", "entry.Item1");
    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = (entry.Item2);
//Run through your export options or whatever here, then export
}
```

Basically, the list allows you to loop through as many entries as you want, while still giving you the filename and entry name.